# Replace ) in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, digits, chars

How do I replace `)` when it comes after 1, 2, or 3 digits (not chars, and without removing the digit(s) themselves)?

Comment: I can't duplicate this. What are you replacing? The entire string `')'` or the parenthesis only `)`? Can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: sorry this was not clear enough. Yes, I was trying to replace the parenthesis only.

Comment: I have a text where parentheses are often used, such as (adsf adsf). There are frequent places where you find (reference adsf, 34). I was trying to replace the ) with )\n (introducing a new line, but only in those instances where the 1,2,or 3 digits come right before the ), not other occurences of ) e.g. (reference asdf, 3) or (reference adf, 245).

Answer (score 2):

Find what: `((?<!\d)\d{1,3})\)`

Replace with: `$1`

This ensures that the `)` comes after 1 to 3 digits (no more, no less).

Just append your replacement text to the end of `$1`. For example, if you want to replace it with the word `TEST`, your replacement would be `$1TEST`

Comment: This doesn't work at the beginning of line like: `123)`

Comment: Good point. Updated answer. I just remembered Notepad++ allows negative lookbehinds if they aren't variable length.

Comment: Well, It's  OK now .

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

- Find: `((^|[^\d])\d{1,3})\)`
- Replace `\1`

And don't forget to enable te regular expressions in the panel.

Visit [this link](https://regex101.com/r/oO2pqC/1) to try a working demo.

Comment: I am trying to replace "abc digit" with "efg digit", but replacing "abc \d" with  \1, regexp ON, is removing the digit. e.g. abc 1 and abc 2 are replaced with efg

Comment: String: `abc 4` - Find: `[A-Za-z]+ (\d)` - Replace: `efg \1` - Result: `efg 4`